# Locking and synchronization

Tags: c#, .net, locking, filesystemwatcher

I'm having a hard time figuring out the problem with the following code:

```
public void InitList(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        /// do something
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Process Failed:" + e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);

        _watcher.Path = textBox2.Text;

        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

I do have FileStreams, but I'm closing those properly. and I believe those are not the issue.

When I run the program first time, it goes to the catch with the exception: `File cannot be accessed.` With the second file copied to the directory, it gives me:
`object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code`.  This exception is given on `monitor.exit(lockobject)`.

**Rough IDEA about my program, and what I'm trying achieve:**

There is a FileSystemWatcher running, when it picks up the file changed I process this file and report it on the UI (ListBox). Can you explain what could be causing the exception I am seeing?

Comment: It is pretty rare that you can read the file for which you got the FSW event.  Since another process is busy modifying the file.  You have to wait, arbitrarily long, until that process closed the file.  Calling Monitor.Exit() when you didn't acquire the monitor is an obvious bug.

Comment: There is no other process running in the background that takes control of the files. Because I simply copy/paste the file into the folder. So when FSW fires. It fires off 4 events (as per msdn fsw manual), now I have a logic in place to suppress those four and get in only one. But my lock doesn't seem to work properly for me.

Comment: here is my code if you want to checks: http://pastebin.com/DyqACh9g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missunderstood what `Monitor.TryEnter(obj)` does, if it returns false you do not have to exit again, because you never entered!

Usually you use `Monitor` like this:

```
void MyMethod() {
  if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj)) {
    // Do stuff
    // Release lock
    Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
  } else {
    // We didn't get a lock, crash? Log? 
  }
}
```

Given the exception you are getting it might be that a delay is needed though, I've encountered issues where the filesystemwatcher fired events before the "offending" application had closed its stream, ie a collision in having the file open. There is no "general" rule of thumb on how long the delay have to be, but aim for something higher than the disk latency, especially for network drives! Ie on an SSD you might get away with 10 ms whilst closer to 100 ms might be needed for networked hard drives.

Comment: I tried your way it's still giving me the exception on the catch, System.IO exception, the process cannot access the file.

Comment: @user726720 Now that has nothing to do with threading, that is just that someone else is having the file opened for modification :) Are you sure you are closing the file properly after reading/modifying it?

Comment: @user726720 Then someone else is having the file open for modification. Try having a small delay and see if that works better. Your code could be firing before the file is closed.

Comment: I have put a delay of 1000ms, but that seems to push the FSW to run 4 times on each detection

Comment: it seems working fine. I have put a delay of 75ms, 1000ms was way too much. Please put your idea as an answer so I may accept it Thank you